# php не загружает xml

Tags: php, xml

Делал `xml parser` на `Js`. На моем компьютере все работает нормально. Но на другом компьютере он не скачивает `xml`, долго грузится и ничего не скачивает.
А на третьем он из 2 `xml` скачивает только 1
в чем может быть проблема?
использую  `wampp server`, `php5`

`xml` загружаю  курсы валют из [www.nationalbank.kz](http://www.nationalbank.kz/rss/rates.xml) и погоду из [www.eurometeo.ru](http://www.eurometeo.ru/kazahstan/astana/export/xml/data).

код `php`

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
    $filename = $_GET["url"];
    $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
    $contents = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
      $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo($contents);
?>
```

Comment: может в php запрещен allow_url_include ?

Comment: включил, все ровно не хочет загружать

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте включить вывод ошибок в php: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` и `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`. И посмотрите какая возникает ошибка. Возможно ваш запрос блокирует firewall.
Попробуйте этот код:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  $filename = $_GET["url"];
  $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
  echo $contents;
?>
```